# When is the edit button disabled?

Tags: support, edits

Sometimes I see that the edit link under questions/answers is disabled, and I can't improve such posts. However, I can still share or flag.

[image]

Under what circumstances the edit option is disabled?

Comment: There are various possible reasons, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681/248731

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The option to suggest an edit is disabled when there's already a suggested edit pending, your edit suggestion privileges have been temporarily suspended, or the suggested edits queue is full. When you hover with your mouse over the disabled edit link, you'll see a tooltip that explains that.

Once you have [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), the "edit" link will always be enabled. If there is a suggested edit pending, clicking "edit" will give you the option to approve or reject (or improve) the edit.

**See also: [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)** in the global FAQ

Comment: When your edit suggestions have been temporarily suspended there is a message after clicking on edit "You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits - please review your edit history." The link has to be live to set the message. (With a moderator ban reviewing the history may not be helpful.)