# What to do when reviewing a post which needs to be edited but I can't edit it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

While [reviewing first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) sometimes I find posts that clearly need to be edited, but I can't do it either, because my edit queue is full or the post is waiting for an edit suggestion to be approved (my [edit button is disabled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295571/when-is-the-edit-button-disabled)). So the only action I can take are *"No Action Needed"* and *"Skip"*.

I don't feel like I should select any of them, since it **does need to be edited** (so, an action is needed) and in the "help" link it is said:

> click Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next item

... but **I am sure what needs to be done** (it needs to be edited and, actually, it was sometimes).

So, What should I do?

I think it's better just click "Skip", but I think it's not the best option (it's like I didn't review the post).

It would be good if it would be there another option like, "Needs to be edited" or whatever you like to call it.

Comment: You've done a *lot* of reviews.  When you can no longer make any useful improvements then it is time to call it a day, it doesn't all have to be done by just you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip it. Another user can review the post then. That's what the "Skip" button is for; if you don't know how to review it correctly, or if you simply cannot review it correctly.

Alternatively you can bookmark the review page or the post, and edit it as soon as you're allowed to (given that it wasn't edited by someone other in the meantime).

Just don't click "No Action Needed", because that's definitely the wrong option.